# Symfony-cmf simple cms tutorial bug

Tags: fixtures, symfony-cmf

I am tryin' to proceed this tutorial http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/cookbook/creating_a_cms/getting-started.html.

After this command:
php app/console doctrine:phpcr:fixtures:load

I've got following error:

PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 2 passed to Doctrine\Bundle\PHPCRBundle\Initializer\GenericInitializer::__construct() must be of the type array, none given

This error was discussed here https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrinePHPCRBundle/issues/119

But I'am still cannot find the right configuration.

Can anyone write what dependencies I have to fix to make tutorial work?
Here is my composer.json "require" section:

```
"php": ">=5.3.3",
"symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
"twig/extensions": "~1.0",
"symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
"symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
"symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
"sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
"sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
"sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
"incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
"doctrine/phpcr-bundle": "dev-master as 1.0.0",
"doctrine/phpcr-odm": "dev-master as 1.0.0",
"jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "1.0.0",

"symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle": "1.0.*@alpha",
"symfony-cmf/menu-bundle": "1.0",
"sonata-project/doctrine-phpcr-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
"symfony-cmf/tree-browser-bundle": "@dev",
"doctrine/data-fixtures": "1.0.0",

"phpcr/phpcr-utils": "dev-master as 1.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

those tutorials are out of date, i have days struggling with the symfony cmf docs, but i fynally got dependencies working thanks to @dbu take a look at my [composer.json](https://gist.github.com/metalvarez/10334865)and take a look to the [question SymfonyCMF RoutingBundle Doctrine PHPCR configuration error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853037/symfonycmf-routingbundle-doctrine-phpcr-configuration-error)